Weighted Mann-Whitney U test
I wonder if there is package (R or Python) to perform weighted Mann-Whitney U test? So far only came across: jhu_pub
But this is too complicated for me to get through. Are there simpler instructions on how to code it?

This depends on what you mean by "weighted".  If you mean sampling weights, then the methods are presented by Lumley & Scott and implemented in R by survey::svyranktest. Strictly speaking, this is a weighted Wilcoxon rank-sum test rather than a weighted Mann-Whitney, and that's not exactly equivalent after weighting, but it's close enough.
The paper by Xie and Priebe that you link is completely different: it's trying to use different weights to give higher power.  I don't know of any implementation, but you can do something similar with weighted logrank tests such as those in the nphRCT package. These were invented for survival analysis but can perfectly well be used with uncensored data.
